# Как заменить обратный слэш на два обратных слэша (PHP)

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
$string = "opentext,opentext\textopen222";
```

мне нужно одинарный обратный слэш заменить на два обратных слэша. 
Попробовал так:
`$string = preg_replace('\\','\\\\',$string);` - выдаёт ошибку:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: А у вас там нет обратного слеша, но есть символ табуляции: `\t`. Чтобы этого избежать используйте одинарные кавычки.

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры вы же вроде бы уже разобрались с разницей между двойными и ординарными кавычками. Или нет?

Comment: Позвольте пожалуйста поинтересоваться, а для чего Вы мне минусуете? ГлубокоУважаемые товарищи, поясните мне глупому - почему задав нормальный адекватный вопрос я всегда получаю минус? Этот сайт создан для того чтобы новички задавали вопросы или я что то недопонимаю?

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры не могу утверждать на 100%, но вероятно минусуют за то, что по тексту ошибки гугл первой же ссылкой выдает решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $string);
```

или

```
preg_replace('/\\/', '\\\\\\', $string);
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c186bd060841cffc71f475d395750c8a105b9ec)

Конкретно ваша ошибка

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

происходит из-за некорректного фильтра регулярного выражения. Вы забыли указать в нем разделители.

[Синтаксис регулярных выражений в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Так же, как уже правильно заметили, у вас в строке не обратный слеш `\`, а символ табуляции `\t`. Что бы комбинация `\t` рассматривалась как два символа `\` и `t` - необходимо для строки использовать одинарные, а не двойные кавычки:

```
$string = 'opentext,opentext\textopen222';
```

Comment: в этом варианте выдает вместо  opentext\textopen222  пишет   opentext extopen222 , в в этом варианте preg_replace('/\\/', '/\\\\/', $string); - ошибку показывает:  Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры `$string = "opentext,opentext\textopen222";` откуда строка берёться? просто "\t" символ табуляции в вашем случае.

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры поправил preg_replace, а так да, Наумов опередил - `\t` - это символ табуляции. Замените в первой строке двойные кавычки на одинарные и все заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала ознакомтесь - http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

У Вас в строке нет обратного слеша. В данном случае \t это табуляция.
Вы можете заменить букву "t" перед слешем на любую другую, которая не входит в список последовательностей php, либо просто поменять двойные кавычки на одинарные.

Тогда ответ от rjhdby, будет для Вас решением.